# Filepond add auth header before rendering the image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, filepond

I am using filepond plugin in my Vue app. It fits well with my apps requirement.
Currently my backend services are serving images over JWT Authentication.
How can I add custom header to the filepond to load the image in the component?

Below is what I have achieved

```
<file-pond
    ref="file"
    name="filepond"
    :label-idle="placeholder"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    drop-validation="true"
    style-panel-layout="compact circle"
    style-button-remove-item-position="center bottom"
    style-panel-aspect-ratio="1:1"
    :allow-image-crop="true"
    image-crop-aspect-ratio="1:1"
    :files="src"
    :server="{
      url: 'http://192.168.0.100',

      load: {
        url: './process',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'x-customheader': 'Hello World'
        },
        withCredentials: false
      }
    }"
  />
```

Even after the component is mounted still the server options is not called and my image is throws a 401 error

Comment: What does the `src` property look like? Make sure each item has a `type` property set to `"local"`. See the second example here: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#files

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.
In order to render remote image url, you need to supply it with extra image properties, in this case `local`.

Read here in details - https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#files

```
<file-pond
    ref="file"
    name="filepond"
    :label-idle="placeholder"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    drop-validation="true"
    style-panel-layout="compact circle"
    style-button-remove-item-position="center bottom"
    style-panel-aspect-ratio="1:1"
    :allow-image-crop="true"
    image-crop-aspect-ratio="1:1"
    :files="[
      {
        source: 'http://your-image-url',
        options: {
           type: 'local'
        }
      }
    ]"
    :server="{
      url: 'http://192.168.0.100',

      load: {
        url: './process',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'x-customheader': 'Hello World'
        },
        withCredentials: false
      }
    }"
  />
```